# How to import the following constructor so it creates a new object every time?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, ecmascript-6

This file initialize Parse and export the defined Parse objects:

**store.js**

```
import Parse from 'parse'

Parse.initialize('APP_ID', 'CLIENT_ID')

const ParseProject = Parse.Object.extend('Project')
var Project = new ParseProject()
var Query = new Parse.Query(ParseProject)

export {
  Project,
  Query
}
```

This one uses these objects to perform a save operation.

**main.js:**

```
import {Project, Query} from '../store'

export default {
  submit () {
    const project = {
      title: this.title,
      content: this.content
    }
    Project.save(project).then((result) =>
      console.log('Success:', result)
    )  
  }
}
```

It works, but the same object is being saved every time (my app is a single page app with no reload).

So if you click `submit()` many times you get:

```
 ParseObjectSubclass {className: "Project", _objCount: 0, id: "vIqpMEUPyD"}
 ParseObjectSubclass {className: "Project", _objCount: 0, id: "vIqpMEUPyD"}
 ParseObjectSubclass {className: "Project", _objCount: 0, id: "vIqpMEUPyD"}
```

How to import those Parse objects so I create a different Parse object each time?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the internals of your modules how the saved state of `Project` is used, but if I needed to create an new instance every time before saving, I would use:

**store.js**

```
let ProjectFactory = () => new ParseProject()
```

**main.js**

```
let saved_project // define in the scope where it's needed to be used
submit () {
  saved_project = ProjectFactory().save(project)...
}
```